# Running service spacenavd start not same as /etc/init.d/spacenavd start

Tags: boot, upstart, services, init.d

I have an application which makes use of a 3dconnexion space mouse. It works fine when using the `spacenavd` daemon however I'm having issues getting the daemon to run at boot or as a service.

$ sudo service spacenavd start

in /var/log/spnavd.log

```
Spacenav daemon 0.5
failed to open config file /etc/spnavrc: No such file or directory. using defaults.
Device detection, parsing /proc/bus/input/devices
using device: /dev/input/event5
device name: 3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator
trying to open X11 display ":0.0"
XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
failed to open X11 display ":0.0"
waiting for X socket file to appear
```

When I run the system V init script however, I don't have any issues:

$ sudo /etc/init.d/spacenavd start

in /var/log/spnavd.log

```
Spacenav daemon 0.5
failed to open config file /etc/spnavrc: No such file or directory. using defaults.
Device detection, parsing /proc/bus/input/devices
using device: /dev/input/event5
device name: 3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator
trying to open X11 display ":0"
XAUTHORITY=/home/sam/.Xauthority
```

The problem is that I need the daemon to start from boot instead of launching it manually which requires sudo access.

### Edit (suggestion from muru)

I made the following upstart script

```
description "Spacenavd upstart script. Starts after lightdm to allow for binding with the Xorg server"
author "Samuel Charreyron"

start on started lightm
stop on shutdown

pre-start script
    echo "Starting spacenavd daemon"
end script

script 
    env DISPLAY=:0.0
    exec /usr/sbin/spacenavd -v -d 2> /var/log/spnavd.log
end script

pre-stop script
    echo "Stopping spacenavd daemon"
    # detect daemon's process id
    pid=`cat /var/run/spnavd.pid 2>/dev/null`
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        pid=`ps -e | grep spacenavd | awk '{ print $1 }'`
        if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
             echo 'spacenavd daemon is not running, nothing to do.'
             exit 1
        fi
    fi
    kill $pid
end script
```

I see that spacenavd cannot connect to the Xorg server. In fact, any upstart script that is run by root seems unable to use Xorg. How can I do so, since spacenavd needs sudo access to the USB devices?

Comment: Does spacenavd have an Upstart configuration file?

Comment: I don't think so. It relies on System V I believe.

Comment: Then I don't see how it is a problem with Upstart. Upstart starts sysv init scripts without any problem. Something might be causing it to fail.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think the way upstart starts the sysv init script, it cannot connect to the Xorg server.

Comment: It's possible Upstart starts it before it starts X. And without an Upstart configuration file, we cannot order it as well. IMHO the simplest way would be for you to write a startup script that restarts the service once X starts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I supppose [the upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) is what I should look at?

Comment: Yes. A simple `task` with a `start on started lightdm` (or whatever your Display Manager is).

Answer (score 1):

The root does not have access to Xserver by default. In order to enable it, you need to copy your /home/sam/.Xauthority  file to /root/.Xauthority

```
sudo cp /home/sam/.Xauthority /root/
```

After the reboot simply enable the spacenavd daemon at the boot:

```
sudo service spacenavd enable
```

And start the spacenavd service:

```
sudo service spacenavd start
```